# How to style Facebook logout dialog window

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-dialogfragment

I need that facebook logout dialog will be in my dark theme style, but when i'm setting my activity to dark theme, it won't apply. 
And can't create dialog for this action by my self, so here's question, how to style it?
 I have the same problem with facebookbutton, but i just replace it by my own and handle `loginButton.performClick();`. But how do the same with dialog i don't have ideas